# Saving string decimal number to one element in string array

Tags: c#, arrays, string, numbers, decimal

I have a problem saving decimal number from string into one element of array. Example: I would like to save String=" 5.2/2" to string array [0]="5.2" [1]="2" the problem here is that the user can write everything between numbers and the program will ignore it...

This is my saving number program.
Right now it saves 5.2 as 52...

```
static string[] saving_numbers(string string_undone)
{
  string[] String_array = new string[string_undone.Length];

  String_array[0] += string_undone[0];

  int Help_index = 0;
  for (int i = 1; i < string_undone.Length; i++)
  {
      if (string_undone[i] > 47 & string_undone[i] < 60)
      {
          if (string_undone[i-1] =='-' & Help_index==0)
          {
              Console.Write("Error: you gave us negative number which is not allowed!");
              Main();
              break;

          }
          if (string_undone[i - 1] < 46 | string_undone[i - 1] > 59 | string_undone[i - 1] == '/')
          {
              Help_index++;
              String_array[Help_index] += string_undone[i];

          }
          else
          {
              String_array[Help_index] += string_undone[i];
          }
      }
  }
  return String_array;
}
```

My program has to find the answer to this "4 ^ 7 / 2.5 * 3.1" I don't know if I'm blind or just that stupid but I simply can't solve this little thing

I can't use things like String.Split() or Char.IsDigit... Only things i can use are basic functions for work with separate signs and function that can return Length of string And i can use Convert.ToDouble which i later use for converting string elements into double

Comment: Well parsing an expression is not so _little thing_

Comment: I wrote a math expression parser a while back, if you need it now: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/274093/Math-Parser-NET

Comment: I can't use any library or anything... I can only use basic .Net functions Later a convert those string numbers or elements into double with Convert.ToDouble which i can use.

Comment: If it is not a homework, you may want to use [this](https://ncalc.codeplex.com/)

Comment: @Mike -- You can always look at my source code and see how I did it so you can get some ideas

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have some help by the following .NET Framework properties and methods:

- [Char.IsDigit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0t641e58%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [Char.IsNumber()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yk2b3t2y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [String.Split()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

And if you want to go for a more advanced way of deciphering your input string, you can go and use the [`RegEx` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to slice your input string into processable components (digits and operators actually).

This task is not so trivial and might be **made easier by making some assumptions** about the input string in question. One important assumption could be:

- Between numbers and operators must be a blank space.

Then you can start like this:

```
// Get the individual elements
String[] components = string_undone.Split(" ");

// Now detect all available decimals...
List<Decimal> decimals = new List<Decimal>;
Decimal number = null;
foreach(String s in components)
{
  if(Decimal.TryParse(s, out number)
    decimals.Add(number);
}
```

Hope this helps and gets you into the right direction.

Comment: I can't use things like String.Split() or Char.IsDigit... Only things i can use are basic functions for work with separate signs and function that can return Length of string
And i can use Convert.ToDouble which i later use for converting string elements into double

Comment: Why can't you use those things?

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those places where regular expressions are called for:

```
var reg = new Regex(@"\s*([0-9.]+).([0-9.]+)");
var match = reg.Match(" 5.2/2");
var first = match.Groups[1].Value;  // = "5.2"
var second = match.Groups[2].Value;     // = "2"
```

I've also tested it with "123.4+56" & "3;5.6"

Answer (score 0):

Could you check your string with:

`string str;
  str.Contains('.');`
By **"Contains"** check if you have "." or "/" or anything else

`str.Split('.');`

By **"Split"** keep number between character inside array and save them.

Pay attention to priority in operation and check them by switch case and you by yourself put parentheses for them according those priority.

Answer (score 0):

You're not writing the decimal because the ascii value is 46.

```
if (string_undone[i] > 47 & string_undone[i] < 60)
    ...
```

Because it is less than your range the if statement is never entered and the decimal place is not written to your string.

Comment: Yea i'we seen that now and I'm trying to figure it out but so far its not working for me. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Mike BTW, you are using the binary operators in your code. It works the way you expect with bool comparisons, but I believe you mean to be using the logical comparison operators &&, and ||.